# Selecting part of an array to write into

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm building up a composite of a number of byte arrays. I'd like to do this quickly but looking for a smart way of doing this:

```
uint A = 1000;
uint B = 2000;

Key[0:3] = BitConverter.GetBytes(A);
Key[4:7] = BitConverter.GetBytes(B);
```

I cannot see an easy way to do this. I do not want to use LINQ. Where BitConverter.GetBytes(A) returns 4 bytes. Of course I can do 16 assignments but this is messy. Is there any good looking syntax that is fast?

Comment: That's not the exact duplicate. This one possibly asks for list(array) manipulation in range-based manner, and not just about how to copy array parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Array.Copy method for each of the GetBytes() result.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)